# How can I get a definite child of div without class/id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I use second/third div in JS/JQuery without using class or id on this element?

```
<div class="parentcontainer">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

And also is there any possibility to find out what child element by number(order) it is? Like:

```
  <div class="parentcontainer">
                <div class="hey"></div>
                <div class="hey"></div>
                <div class="hey"></div>
                <div class="hey"></div>
          </div>

$('.hey').click(function(){
// what element by number is that?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:eq()`

```
var secondInnerDiv = $('div div:eq(1)');
var thirdInnerDiv = $('div div:eq(2)');
```

```js
$('div div:eq(1), div div:eq(2)').css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentcontainer">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

**Or** `:lt()/gt()`

```
var secondAndThirdInnerDiv = $('div div:gt(0):lt(2)');
```

```js
$('div div:gt(0):lt(2)').css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentcontainer">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Use `index()`

```
$(this).index()
```

```js
$('div div').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).index());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentcontainer">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can work with this I quess:

https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd use for example:

```
div > div:first-child {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

[Here is a **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hL8q7wj4/)

Note that `div > div` selects all the immediate div childrens. For the demo I made it highlight only the first child using `:first-child`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that gives a hint on one of the approaches

```
var allDivs = $(".parentcontainer > div");
var secondDiv = $(allDivs.get(1));
var thirdDiv = $(allDivs.get(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) method:

```
var secondAndThirdDiv = $("div div").slice(1,3);
```

You basically specify the range of elements you want (`0` index based of course).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/k4pm1fxw/

```
// return position
$('.parentcontainer').on('click', '.hey', function(){
    alert($(this).index()); 
});
// select nth with eq
$('.parentcontainer').find('.hey').eq(2).css('background', 'red');
```